# How to make dialogflow distinguish two similar entities?

Tags: entity, dialogflow-es

I need a help about distinguish similar entities.

In my case I have one entity called '@agent' with some entries, two of them is 'Iago Campos' and 'Iago Coutinho'. I have an intent called 'transfer' that is triggered when user says that want to talk to someone. When user says 'I want to talk with Iago' dialogflow doesn't match any of the 'Iago'

I want to know if it's possible to make dialogflow ask to user if he wants to talk with Iago Campos or Iago Coutinho. I was looking aboult Fulfillment, but for many reasons I'm not confortable using webhook to just distinguish agents...

@Agents entries

[image: Entities from @agents]

Answer (score 0):

Dialog Flow doesn't match any of the “lago”  because it does not know what decision it has to  take since it found 2 matches “lago Campos” and “lago Coutinho”.
If you proceed to say “Campos” dialog flow will find only one match “lago campos” and it will return it. It would be ideal to remove the world “lago” since it causes redundancy in your system.

On the other hand a fast solution would be to create another Intent specifically for when the user enters the word “lago” and that it is linked with a trigger that replies what “Lago”  is it referring to. Here the final user can choose one “lago” or another.
So here I could suggest creating this behavior using a Fulfillment webhook  in that way you can use it from the same intent